# Image streaming with OpenCV and flask - Why imencode is needed?

Tags: python, opencv, flask

I have a flask web application which reads one image and display it in my web browser

## app.py

```
from flask import Response
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
import cv2

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

def GetImage():
    global img
    while True:
        yield(b'--frame\r\n' b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + bytearray(img) + b'\r\n')

@app.route("/stream")
def stream():
    return Response(GetImage(), mimetype = "multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame")

if(__name__ == "__main__"):
    img = cv2.imread("Cat.jpg", 0)
    app.run(debug = True, threaded = True, use_reloader = False)
```

## index.html

```
<html>
    <body>
        <img src="{{ url_for('stream') }}">
    </body>
</html>
```

This example doesn´t work, because the image isn´t displayed in the browser.
But when I change `GetImage` in the following way the image will be displayed in the browser:

```
def GetImage():
    global img
    (flag, encodedImage) = cv2.imencode(".jpg", img)
    while True:
        yield(b'--frame\r\n' b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + bytearray(encodedImage) + b'\r\n')
```

So why do I need this `imencode`? The image is stored as `jpg` on my harddisk so why do I have to encode it again as `JPG`?

Comment: opencv decodes the .jpg since it is assumed that you want to process the pixels, so if you don't want to use imencode then read the file directly

Comment: @eyllanesc what do you mean with "Read the file directly"?

Comment: the .jpg is a file so you can read it directly: `with open("your.jpg") as f: ...`

Comment: To say it another way, you have to encode it because `imread` decodes it. If you don't want to encode it, then don't decode it first, i.e. don't open it with `imread`, open it as if it were a file of data (because it is). On the other hand, if you want to process the image, then you need it decoded to play with the pixels, and then you need to encode it again as a binary string.

Comment: if you want to display only one image then maybe use `send_file` or create HTML with tag `<img>`. You need `imencode` only when you have raw data - ie. array with pixel - and you have to convert it to jpeg data. `imread` reads jpeg data and convert to array so later you have to convert array back to jpeg data. If you use standard `open()` then it will not convert jpeg data to array so you don't have to use `imencode`. Probably if you open in bytes mode -  `open(..., 'rb').read()` - then you will no need `bytesarray()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have JPEG file then you can use standard `open()` and `read()` to read it as raw bytes data without decompressing it to array with all pixels - so later you don't have to compress it back to JPEG data using `imencode()`

```
 img = open("Cat.jpg", "rb").read()
```

and then you can display it

```
 b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n'+ img + b'\r\n'
```

I read it directly in bytes mode - `open(..., 'rb')` - so I don't have to use `bytearray()` to convert string to bytes. Besides, reading in text mode it could convert some chars (like "new line") and create incorrect data.

---

But to send single file you can use `send_file()`

```
@app.route("/image")
def image():
    return send_file('Cat.jpg')
```

---

Working example.

Opening http://127.0.0.1:5000/stream in Chrome it shows image.

My Firefox had problem to display image - it was reading data all time - till I added `time.sleep()`

I also added version which adds header `Content-Length:`

```
from flask import Flask, Response, send_file
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Hello World"

def get_image():
    while True:
        yield(b'--frame\r\n'
              b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n'+ img + b'\r\n')
        time.sleep(0.01) # my Firefox needs some time to display image / Chrome displays image without it

def get_image_with_size():
    length = str(len(img)).encode() # convert to bytes
    while True:
        yield(b'--frame\r\n'
              b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n'
              b'Content-Length: ' + length + b'\r\n'
              b'\r\n'+ img + b'\r\n')
        time.sleep(0.01) # my Firefox needs some time to display image / Chrome displays image without it

@app.route("/stream")
def stream():
    return Response(get_image(), mimetype="multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame")

@app.route("/image")
def image():
    return send_file('Cat.jpg')

if(__name__ == "__main__"):
    img = open('Cat.jpg', 'rb').read()
    app.run()
```

Comment: Thank you. I´ve tried it yesterday on my own and I´ve got an empty image in my browser. But this example helps me. And I can confirm the `sleep` "problem" with `Firefox`. I only have `Firefox` at this PC and it doesn´t work without `sleep`. It is really anoing that `Edge` doesn´t display anything and `Internet Explorer` display an empty image when I add my `index.html` to the routing of `/`.